# How to add pivot header into pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm tring to collect some data from my db, and using `pandas` to make a excel file.
The dataframe structure I got like below:

```
>>> df

                                            2020-05-21~2020-05-27
input_cost   jim    bob     companyc            17770.65                17770.65 
                            companye            3392.73                 3392.73
                            companyd            2892.30                 2892.30
                            companyf            22843.67                22843.67
             casy   dave    company_a           160.93                  160.93                                                      
                            company_b           160.93                  160.93
```

And then I want to add a header to it , then export it to excel file by using `df.to_excel`

```
# expected output
                                                date
data_source  sale   leader  entity_name       2020-05-21~2020-05-27       sum 
input_cost   jim    bob     companyc            17770.65                17770.65
                            companye            3392.73                 3392.73
                            companyd            2892.30                 2892.30
                            companyf            22843.67                22843.67
             casy   dave    company_a           160.93                  160.93                                                                     
                            company_b           160.93                  160.93
```

Sorry that I'm a new bee to `pandas`, how can I make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rename_axis`:

```
# rename index
df = df.rename_axis(['data_source', 'sale', 'leader', 'entity_name'])

# add level to columns
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['date'], df.columns])
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried but got some error like `NotImplementedError: isna is not defined for MultiIndex`

Comment: And my colums is like `MultiIndex([('2020-05-21~2020-05-27',)],)`